# Is the group isomorphism $\exp(\alpha x)$ from the group $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\times)$ unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm having a problem trying to find the simplest way of proving this, which has most probably been solved a hundred of times but I am unable to find a good reference.

I have two groups, $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\times)$. I am trying to prove that the only class of isomorphisms between them is the class $F = \{f: f(x) = \exp(\alpha x), $ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}\}$. Existence is easy to prove: what I'm having trouble with is a clean algebraic uniqueness proof.

Does anyone know the proof or a reference containing this proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find some facts about the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(xy)$ in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, it may not be true.

Consider $(\Bbb R,+)$ as an infinite (continuum) dimension vector space over $\Bbb Q$, and fix a basis (Hamel basis).

Then, any automorphism of this vector space (for example permuting the basis) will be an automorphism of $(\Bbb R,+)$, and you can compose this with any exponential.

Comment: I see... so, do you think the only way to make this statement true would be to impose the preservation of the strict total order?

Comment: Yes, or equivalently the continuity.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!